NextJs : put a next js website deployed by vercel on google console
I tried to use Html tag to verify my ownership of the website for google console.
I added the meta tag like this:
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'English | Topia',
  description: 'Improve Your English Speaking skill',
  verification: { google: "MY-COPIED-VERIFICATION-CODE" },
}

and if you inspect, you'll find the meta tag, however when I verify on google console, it gives an error saying *
"Verification method:
HTML tag
Failure reason:
Could not find your site. Please check that you provided the correct URL for your property." *
I am not sure if I can do it through vercel or it may be another way
here is the website link to take a look at the tag:
https://english-topia.vercel.app/
